# Unable to create temporary object directory when pushing to Azure VM

Tags: git, azure, ssh

Am trying to create remote git repository in linux VM using azure, i want to push  from git bash with ssh authentification. but I end up having this issue when I tried to push to the created repository on my VM on azure. so this I what I have done so far:
On my VM Azure:

```
$ sudo adduser git
$ sudo su - git
$ cd
$ mkdir .ssh
$ chmod 700 .ssh
$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
$ cd /var/git
$ mkdir myproject.git
$ cd myproject.git
$ git --bare init
```

On my local machine I'v created ssh keys and copied it to the VM using

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh USER@IP "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

But when we tried to push to it we get this error:

```
$ cd myproject_development
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m ’commentaire : ma premiere validation’
$ git remote add origin git@dns_aws_git_server:/var/git/myproject.git
$ git push origin master
```

[image]

Comment: The error itself tends to indicate a permissions problem, but anything that makes it impossible for the Azure VM's `git` command to do an OS-level `mkdir` operation would cause this. The setup looks right so I'm not sure *why* your Azure-VM `git` is unable to make new temporary directories, but that's what to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up finding where the issue was, my repos didnt have permissions as git user so i changed that an the push cmd work fine:

```
chown -R git:git myproject.git
```